# I am trying to import an image with a clear back round, but i continuously receive this error "error: Couldn't open Pictures\ThePenrose.jpg

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
img = pygame.image.load('Documents/pythonPenrose.png').convert_alpha()
imgx = 10
imgy = 10
```

## I beleive this is where the problem is  although im not sure

```
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth,displayHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Penrose ')

pygame.display.update()

gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    print event
    gameDisplay.fill(cyan)
    gameDisplay.blit(img, (imgx, imgy))

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (0,0,800,100))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, dark_red, (0,100,800,7))
```

## the 2 lines above create a header (likely not relevent)

Comment: Can you post the code that is actually producing the error? Because this is not it.

Comment: This is definately the code producing the error, although it is a part of a much larger script, would you like to see more of it

Comment: why do you say that it is not the correct code? @SlaterTyranus

Comment: This code cannot possibly be creating the error, as the error message you have specified mentions ThePenrose.jpg, which doesn't appear anywhere in this code. You can't get an error for something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The filename you provide seems strange to me:

```
"Documents/pythonPenrose).png"
```

Does it not need to be:

```
"Documents/pythonPenrose.png" #whithout the )
```

or even

```
"Documents/python/Penrose.png"
```

That your error says that you have a problem loading a *.jpg although you provide a *,png also suggests that there is something wrong with your filename.

Comment: I Fixed the miss placed parnthase, but i got the same error although investegate the jpg, and the problem with the file name

Comment: There is a ) missing at the end of this line:            img = pygame.image.load('Documents/pythonPenrose.png'.convert_alpha()